# .py file not opening in command-line when numpy is installed

Tags: python, numpy, command-line

Whenever I want to open a .py file which has numpy imported on it, it doesn't want to open (it opens for a millisecond and immediately shuts down)

I've written some rubbish code to try it out using spyder. I've tried the code when numpy isn't imported (version1) and when it is imported(version2):

Version 1:

```py
#import numpy as np

def testing(inputUser):
    print("Whatever something somwhtng" + inputUser)

user = input("Write somth:")
testing(user)

input()
```

Version 2:

```py
import numpy as np

def testing(inputUser):
    print("Whatever something somwhtng" + inputUser)

user = input("Write somth:")
testing(user)

input()
```

When I run both codes in the spyder console, everything works like it's supposed to. It also works when I open the files through the command prompt (Windows 10)
When I open the .py version 1 by right-clicking on it and choosing 'open with python', it also works.
However, even if I'm not using numpy, as soon as it is imported the .py file won't open (opened the same way as version 1).
I have no clues as to why it isn't working, anyone has any ideas?

p.s. I am new to stackoverflow and this is my first question. If the question isn't detailed enough or structured correctly, please tell me I'll change it.

clarification:
I'm using Anaconda3
My operating system is Windows 10 version 1809 (64-bit)

Comment: How are you running your files at the command line? Are you doing `python name_of_your_script.py` or `./name_of_your_script.py`? (BTW, I can't reproduce your problem.)

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://superuser.com/questions/1434959/python-script-runs-in-spyder-but-not-in-command-line You should add which system you are using and which anaconda version.

Comment: What operating system? What command are you using to execute it?

Comment: @SimonN I think I didn't express myself correctly, when I try to run my testing.py file I simply right-click the file and select 'open with python', which works for version 1 but not 2
I'll try to change my post and make it clearer

Comment: You still haven't said what OS you're on. Try running it by opening a command prompt first then typing 'python your_script.py' this way the window won't close when it exits and you can read any error message. Have you installed something like Anaconda? Sounds like you may have multiple versions of Python on your system.

Comment: @SimonN I updated my question, at the end I mentioned my operating system and the version of anaconda I'm using
Though I do have 2 versions of python (3.6 and 3.7) installed, could this be the problem?
Also, when I open the file for version 2 using the command prompt, it works...

Comment: If say there's a high chance that you are running it using a version of Python that doesn't have numpy, try what I said to see the error message.

Comment: @SimonN I did try running it with window's command prompt and no errors were mentioned, the .py file was running correctly
(p.s. thank you for all your help!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me that the problem is the version of python being accessed by the right click is not the right one. Try making a python script as follows

```
import sys

print(sys.executable)
```

Then run it in all the ways you've said. If I'm right the output will be different with the right click.